# Process does not close after closing the form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a first form that calls another one and then disappears (frm.visible = false).
This form should not come back after being called once, but it's the main form (the first one that appears when you launch the program). I am trying to make it so when you close the second form, both forms close, I have tried multiple things but all of them leave the process active.

This is the code that I use :

```
private void frmCreation_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            frmProperties frm = new frmProperties();
            frm.Dispose();
        }
        //I have also tried frm.Close() which also does not work
```

This code close the two forms, but the process remains active. How do I counter this?

Comment: Why do you create frm, and then immediately Dispose it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for `Application.Exit()`?

Comment: Hm, I feel really dumb. Even after searching on google, I never thought of this. Thanks

Comment: @MrRoy ... sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees ... ;-)

Answer (score 8):

`Application.Exit()` tells your App to close itself.
`Environment.Exit(0)` tells Windows to kill it.

I prefer the latter since it really closes your app no matter what.

Comment: if Application.Exit() doesn't close your app, it usually means there are other threads or processes still running that should be cleanly stopped.

Answer (score 1):

I can believe the solution here is : Do not handle it.

If the process is still pending that means you are not disposing your resources properly.

Using `Application.Exit()` or asking the system to do it `Environment.Exit(0)` may be logged in the system as an error occurred and you are better to know how to properly close a process than relied on `Application.Exit()`, if you want to close a thread of your app you have to know how to collect those garbage.

You can re-implement the `Dispose` method to Dispose services, sockets, streams, almost everything that has a `.Dispose` available.

```cs
 public class MyClass: IMyClass, IDisposable
    {
        private bool _disposed = false;
        // ...
```

```cs
public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);

    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

```cs
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (_disposed) return;

    if (disposing)
    {
        // dispose your stuff you created in this class
        // do the same for other classes

        // some examples
        /*
        _webClient.Dispose();
        _connector.DataAvailable -= ConnectorHasDataComing
        _socket.Dispose();
        _timer.Dispose();
        _taskLogs.ForEach(x => {
            x.Token.Cancel();
            x.Task.Wait();
            x.Task.Dispose();
        });
        */
    }

    // dispose native events

    _disposed = true;
}
```

If you use `System.Threading.Thread` or `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` or `System.IO.MemoryStream` (or other kind of Stream - Writer/Reader), and others that requires a `CancellationTokenSource`. If you created the ressource in the class when you are disposing the class, use the `Token.Cancel()` method to let it know its parent is being disposed and `.Wait()` for it before calling `.Dispose()`

```
public async Task Run(CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource)
{
    // ...
    while (Running) {
        if (cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested) return;
        // ....
    }

    // ....
    using (var reader = new WaveFileReader(tempFile))
    {
         reader.Position = 0;
         await reader.CopyToAsync(fileWriter,81920, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }
}
```

I found my issue using the Diagnostic Tools when my Debug was still pending on something after closing the app.

[image]

If you use CPU Usage you can click on `Break All` and it set a breakpoint.
You can then see profiler and find what are your top functions, you might find out that your form is disposed but you have a Thread or Task that invokes fields on your form.

[image]

For my case, I was using a filewriter and I implemented IDisposable in that class but it sometimes was about or actual doing a transfer of data between a filereader and itself using `.copyTo` so it was pending without throwing an exception.

[image]

After clicking on one the events, click on `Go to Source code` and place a breakpoint, you may see events that your code is stocked on.

Otherwise, you can use in the same tool the tab `Memory Usage` to take a snapshot and look at the Heap and Objects diff or the tab `CPU Usage` and look at a recorded Profile. If find my `copyTo` issue that way.

You can also run your app with `Throw on all exceptions`
[image]

#### while disposing make sure no one recalls the form or its instance.

Also, if you are using the form event `_FormClosing`

Make sure if you have a modal to cancel the form closing, return and set `e.Cancel = true;` but do not set `e.Cancel = true` if the form is closing. And do not call `this.Close()` in a `_FormClosing()` event that you are handling yourself.

After, you may `.Dispose()` your stuff, but make sure no Dispose methods call the form back like invoking components, since they are being disposed or already disposed.

For people that use the hack that sets the form in an `var instance` to have access to it anywhere, do not dispose it, otherwise you are disposing a form already disposed.